# Call a 'global' function from an object's method

Tags: javascript

I would like to call a function from an object's method. The function is declared in the same scope as the object:

```
function a() {
   return {
      propA: 'something'
   }
}

var b = {
   func: function() {
      var a = a(); //Uncaught TypeError: a is not a function
      console.log(a);
   }
}

b.func();
```

Is there any way how to call `a` in `b.func` without setting it as a property of the `window` object or passing it as a parameter? Thank you.

Comment: Use a different variable name. You're shadowing the outer function. And declaring a function that way *does* set it as a global property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code would be seen by the interpreter as follows,

```
var b = {
   func: function() {
      var a;
      a = a(); // so here a would be undefined
      console.log(a);
   }
}
```

Basically the variable a got hoisted and caused the issue. Use different variable name for that.

Comment: So true, didn't realize that! Thank you, you were the first to answer so the the checkmark goes to you.

Answer (score 1):

As long as it is not important to you that within `b.func` the result of `a()` is not called `a`, yes:

```
function a() {
   return {
      propA: 'something'
   }
}

var b = {
   func: function() {
      var c = a();
      console.log(c);
   }
}

b.func();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you define your `a` function like that it is automatically added to the `window` object:

```js
function a() {
   return {
      propA: 'something'
   }
}

var b = {
   func: function() {
      var a = window.a();
      console.log(a);
   }
}

b.func();
```